# Select statement using OleDbCommand throws InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, oledb

I need to find a record in C# but I get an InvalidOperationException:

```
public static Auto findAuto(int kfznr)
{
    Auto retAuto = new Auto();
    try
    {
        myOleDbConnection.Open();
        string query = "SELECT * FROM Auto WHERE Auto.KFZNR = " + kfznr; 
        
        OleDbCommand select = new OleDbCommand();
        select.Connection = myOleDbConnection;
        select.CommandText = query;
        OleDbDataReader reader = select.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Auto at = new Auto(Convert.ToInt32(reader[0]), Convert.ToString(reader[1]), Convert.ToString(reader[2]));

            retAuto = at;
        }
    }
    catch (OleDbException e)
    {

        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }

    return retAuto;
}
```

I get the error in the while loop at the creation of the new Auto.
When I run the same query in the SQLDeveloper I get one record (take a look at the first screenshot) but in my C# program I get there is no data for my row/cell.

[image: The output from the SQLDeveloper]

When I hover the reader I get the following image. It says that the reader has rows:
[image: Screenshot from Visual Studio]

Hope that you can help me fix this problem.

Comment: Is it possible that one of the columns in the row is null?  Is this Oracle?  Does it return null if the column has an empty string?

Comment: Writing your queries by concatenating string is bad practice, use parameters instead to avoid injecting malicious scripts to your database. BTW you don't need the first instance of you Auto class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use reader.GetValue(0)

```
    public static Auto findAuto(int kfznr)
    {
        Auto retAuto = new Auto();
        try
        {
            myOleDbConnection.Open();
            string query = "SELECT * FROM Auto WHERE Auto.KFZNR = " + kfznr; 

            OleDbCommand select = new OleDbCommand();
            select.Connection = myOleDbConnection;
            select.CommandText = query;
            OleDbDataReader reader = select.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Auto at = new Auto(Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetValue(0)), Convert.ToString(reader.GetValue(1)), Convert.ToString(reader.GetValue(2)));

                retAuto = at;
            }
        }
        catch (OleDbException e)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }

        return retAuto;
    }
```

Also wanted to add...you can access the reader values by column name as well using:

reader["ColumnName"]...don't forget the "" around the name of the column ;)

```
public static Auto findAuto(int kfznr)
{
    Auto retAuto = new Auto();
    try
    {
        myOleDbConnection.Open();
        string query = "SELECT * FROM Auto WHERE Auto.KFZNR = " + kfznr; 

        OleDbCommand select = new OleDbCommand();
        select.Connection = myOleDbConnection;
        select.CommandText = query;
        OleDbDataReader reader = select.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Auto at = new Auto(Convert.ToInt32(reader["col1"]), Convert.ToString(reader["col2"]), Convert.ToString(reader["col3"]));

            retAuto = at;
        }
    }
    catch (OleDbException e)
    {

        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }

    return retAuto;
}
```